# Unity RemoveAt method is not working for an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a script that finds gameobjects with a specific tag. However the gameobject containing this script also has the tag, so I have to remove this gameobejct from the list of founded gameobject with the specific tag.

```
void Update()
    {
        GameObject[] allEntities = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Entity");
        int length = allEntities.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        {
            if (allEntities[i].transform.position == gameObject.transform.position)
            {
                //remove the gameobject with this script from the list allEntites
            }
        }
        Debug.Log(length);
    }
```

I tried to use allEntities.RemoveAt() but a error keeps saying that the list allEntities can not use RemoveAt for some reason. I also tried just Remove() and clear() but they also did not work. The method FindIndex() is experiencing the same problem, and I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: *`keeps saying that the list allEntities can not use RemoveAt for some reason`* please show us a screenshot of the error message saying that

Comment: `i <= length` will access the container out of bounds on the last iteration if the container is not modified inside the loop. If items are removed from the container the problem gets  worse since the length is not recalculated.

Comment: `IList.RemoveAt` is expected to throw `NotSupportedException` if the `IList` has a fixed size (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.removeat?view=net-7.0). Arrays have a fixed size, so it's perfectly reasonable that you can't remove items from them.

Comment: GameObject[] allEntities = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Entity")
                .Where(e => e.transform.position != transform.position).ToArray();

But this solution can be bad by performance reasons. It's better to get the array once rather than in update and don't use linq

Answer (score 1):

It indeed doesn't.

You *could* use a list

```
List<GameObject> allEntities = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Entity").ToList();
```

**however**, still while you remove an item you also shift the index of all the following items. Since you iterate over the original length of the list this would result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

You could do either e.g.

```
var allEntities = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Entity").ToList();
Debug.Log(allEntities.Count);
var i = 0;
while(i < allEntities.Length)
{
    if (allEntities[i].transform.position == gameObject.transform.position)
    {
        allEntities.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}                 
Debug.Log(allEntities.Count);
```

Or instead you could use `Linq` and do e.g.

```
var allEntities = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Entity");
var filteredEntities = allEntities.Where(e => e.transform.position == transform.position).ToList();
```